# How to access an VC++ ActiveX dll with UI from a non-IE browsers?

Tags: javascript, .net, com, cross-browser, activex

I’ve a legacy VC++ ActiveX dll with UIs. 
This ActiveX dll can be used only in the same workstation but through browser (IE only, because of its other dependencies.
Now there is a requirement from the customers that it should be accessible and behave same from other browsers like Chrome, Safari and FF.
Writing plug-ins for each browser, asking the customer to install it and maintaining those plug-ins is not feasible. 
So I tried the following options:

1. With node-ffi ( Node.js addon) but this can be used only for loading and calling native dynamic libraries but not ActiveX instantiating and rendering in browser.

   a.  **Cannot use Node.js -> win32ole as it works only in IE.**
2. Wrapping the unmanaged COM dll to an interop dll, exposing the methods and events from this wrapper, as end points using REST WCF service ( HTTP bindings and WebGet/ WebInvoke contracts attribute).

   a. **The above approach works fine for regular COM dll but not for VC++ ActiveX dll.**

**Is it possible someway to wrap the unmanaged ActiveX dll and expose this wrapper to be consumed by non-IE browsers/ JavaScript, using .NET or any other MS technologies?**

Thank you in advance

Comment: `The above approach works fine for regular COM dll but not for VC++ ActiveX dll. ` Huh?

Comment: Why do we keep maintaining these old programs. It takes up less resources to create a modern program.

Comment: This is a legacy ActiveX developed for a medical software product, decade ago and the underlying code base and dependencies are huge (MFC/ ATL/ STL etc). So rewriting the entire ActiveX is not possible considering the time and available resource. The goal is to use and render the respective UIs in this ActiveX in different browsers like, Chrome, FF, Safari and including IE/ Edge. Any help in any easier direction (only MS tech stack allowed though)

Comment: Hello Schabse, When I said the above approach works fine for a regular COM dll, I meant a COM dll with few interface methods and properties but not any UI in the component. I can consume the regular COM componet methods and properties from browser by exposing the respective end points as WEBGET/ WebInvoke.

Comment: It is (almost) completely impossible to do that.  You need to rewrite.